# Trouble creating a conda environment

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, data-science, jupyter, conda

I am trying to create a conda environment but am running into a lot of trouble. This is my first time using conda (with the intention of using Jupyter notebooks for the first time).

Using macOS, I start by typing into the terminal:

```
conda create --name test_name scikit-learn pandas matplotlib numpy scipy seaborn jupyter statsmodels
```

I am warned:

```
==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 22.9.0
  latest version: 23.3.1
```

but the code proceeds to run until I get two errors:

```
CondaVerificationError: The package for qt-webengine located at /Users/user/opt/anaconda3/pkgs/qt-webengine-5.15.9-h90a370e_4
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/libQt5WebEngineCore.5.15.9.dylib'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

ClobberError: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults/osx-64::llvm-openmp-14.0.6-h0dcd299_0, defaults/osx-64::intel-openmp-2023.1.0-ha357a0b_43547
  path: 'lib/libiomp5.dylib'
```

So I decide to update conda with the suggested command `conda update -n base -c defaults conda`.

This gives me the error:

```
CondaVerificationError: The package for qt-webengine located at /Users/user/opt/anaconda3/pkgs/qt-webengine-5.15.9-h90a370e_4
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/libQt5WebEngineCore.5.15.9.dylib'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.
```

When I tried instead `conda update conda`, I got

```
PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix.
  prefix: /Users/user/opt/anaconda3/envs/test_name
  package name: conda
```

Any advice as to how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Main thing sounds like a corrupted file. Try removing the folder `/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/pkgs/qt-webengine-5.15.9-h90a370e_4` and then rerunning

```
conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```

For the clobbering, that looks like a legitimate bug in the Anaconda metadata. They should have a mutex package to prevent `intel-openmp` and `llvm-openmp` from being installed in the same environment. Please [report this to the `anaconda-issues` repository](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues).